Replace variables value in json from azure devops pipeline variable
I have variables in azure devops pipeline. I have json files on the server. I want to replace the variables values in json file from the variables in azure devops pipeline. I used file transform task. My file is on the server at location C:\agent\_work\r1\a\helm-chart\applicationservice\applicationservice\appsettings.config.json. I have passed the same location in package or folder. However it gives error

##[warning]Can't find loc string for key: Invalidwebapppackageorfolderpathprovided

and the task fails. I am not sure why it is not working.
File transform for me:
steps:
- task: FileTransform@1
  displayName: 'File Transform: '
  inputs:
    folderPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/**/**/appsettings.config.json'
    fileType: json


steps:

task: FileTransform@1

File transform yaml is
displayName: 'File Transform: '
inputs:
folderPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)///**/appsettings.config.json'
fileType: json

In the logs I can see that it is picking up current file at the current location, then why I am getting ##[warning]Can't find loc string for key: Invalidwebapppackageorfolderpathprovided error

If you have additional info to your question, use the [edit] link. Don't post them in comments.

SO is for programming questions

Agree with the answer. In the FileTransform@1 task document, it mentions the folderPath input should be a file path to the package or a folder, not the file itself.

Ensure the folderPath points to the directory containing your JSON file: 'C:\agent\_work\r1\a\helm-chart\applicationservice\applicationservice', not the file itself. You may
Have this as a test to verify you get the right location of the directory.
steps:
- task: FileTransform@1
  displayName: 'File transformation: appsettings.json'
  inputs:
    folderPath: 'C:\agent\_work\r1\a\helm-chart\applicationservice\applicationservice'
    targetFiles: 'appsettings.config.json'
    fileType: json

After which you may use a more refined way:
steps:
- task: FileTransform@1
  displayName: 'File transformation: appsettings.json'
  inputs:
    folderPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/helm-chart/applicationservice/applicationservice'
    targetFiles: 'appsettings.config.json'
    fileType: json

Please crosscheck and verify that your variables follows the expected value and syntax. Look at the examples here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#json-variable-substitution

Azure DevOps FileTransform task variables in yaml


